# avconv: No such file or directory, yet the file exists

Tags: bash, sed, debian, avconv

So I have a lot of mkv files I need to convert to HTML 5 webm files. I used Handbrake, it is what it is.

I decided to make a simple script to help me with this and other future projects. It's just a one liner.

```
avconv -i "'$1'" -c:v copy -c:a copy $(echo "'$1'" | sed 's/mkv/webm/')
```

avconv returns the following when provided with a perfectly valid file path:

```
avconv version 11.9-6:11.9-1~deb8u1, Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 23 2017 21:47:31 with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
'/home/nk/Videos/MKV files to convert/animals.mkv': No such file or directory
```

Yet, I can literally copy/paste the path from the error and ls to it, confirming that it does indeed exist. I think it might have something to do with the quotes, but I need it to accept the entire path, spaces and all. If I do anything less than the double quotes, it will break up the path at the spaces.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Add your script to your question. How do you start your script?

Comment: I suggest to replace `"'$1'"` with `"$1"`.

Comment: Replacing the double quotes with single seems to fix the first half, but the other half with sed seems to remain a problem.